# can I use {{stuff}} in {% statements %} in django?

Tags: django, string-matching, if-statement

Thank you for helping. 
My problem is that for some reason my code doesn't execute my if statement in template:

```
{% if {{game.player}} == {{user.username}} %}
    <a href="/game/stop/">Stop this game</a>
{% else %}
    current user: {{ user.username }}
    game by: {{ game.player }}
{% endif %}
```

When the 'else' statement is executed user.username is indeed = game.player, but for some reason if statement doesn't execute. I did try it without the {{ }} around the game.player and with ' ' just to match the strings. but it wouldn't work and I am quite confused!

thank you for your time:)
blargie-bla

Comment: I would _guess_ `{% if game.player == user.username %}` would be the valid way of doing it, based on the [demos](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs).

Comment: That's not even close to legal use of the Django template engine.  You should review the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#if documentation to see how to reference variables in an if construct.  And then **update** your question based on what you read.

Comment: thanks guys:) i tried it too and wasn't working, but maybe there is another issue then, thank you for your time then! x

Comment: @blargie-bla Is `game.player` a FK to a user? If so, then you'll need something like `game.player.username` to get the username, and `game.player == user` to test for equality.

Comment: yes it is:) in my models for game player = models.ForeignKey(User). thank you for your suggestion, going to try it now!:)

Comment: Dirk thank you so much!!! I have just tried it and {% if game.player.username == user.username %} worked perfectly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
{% if game.player == user.username %}
```

Comment: thank you:) it wasn't working that way either for some reason: probably an issue with something else. but thank you! x